# codeigniter stopped working all of sudden

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax-error

I have CodeIgniter 3.0.0 and I'm hosted on 1and1.com and I'm using PHP 5.5. The site I'm working on used to be working the last time I was working on it. Today, I tried to load the site and I see (I removed part of the path to not show my user info):

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ARRAY, expecting ')' in /htdocs/_smchorus/system/core/Common.php on line 238
```

The only thing I can think that might have change is that I remember moving from php 5.4 to 5.5 recently on the 1and1.com admin panel. I'm not sure why that would break it though. I haven't really messed around with the system code for codeigniter. I tried going back to 5.4 and that didn't fix it.

this line:

```
function get_config(Array $replace = array())
```

is line 238 in question.

```
if ( ! function_exists('get_config'))
{
    /**
     * Loads the main config.php file
     *
     * This function lets us grab the config file even if the Config class
     * hasn't been instantiated yet
     *
     * @param   array
     * @return  array
     */
    function get_config(Array $replace = array())
    {
        static $config;

        if (empty($config))
        {
            $file_path = APPPATH.'config/config.php';
            $found = FALSE;
            if (file_exists($file_path))
            {
                $found = TRUE;
                require($file_path);
```

Comment: Not sure if it's not relevant, but did you change your `config` file? CI should work on PHP 5.4 and up.

Comment: I don't see how this would possibly work: `function get_config(Array $replace = array())`...

It's `array`, not `Array`, unless CodeIgniter has a class called `Array`.

Comment: i guess you have a problem in one of your config files (probably a typo in config.php or something like that)
a config should always be an array
@will this is in the CI core and works perfectly fine...

Comment: I can only recreate this exact error on PHP 4.4.9 http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/32f91eade798fea3fa046c7d9360468184d5b1a1

Comment: The argument being passed to `get_config()` is causing the error. Double check your config file for syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidentally set your php to an older version. Try adding the following to the top of your `index.php` to check if you are in fact using the proper version.

```
echo phpversion(); die();
```

The error does not seem to be in the config or anything. It says its a **parse error**, therefore the keyword `Array` must be causing the problem. And this syntax is not recognized by older versions of php. Hence the check.